# internet explorer was not able to open this internet site the requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.Please try again later

Tags: asp.net

When im try to export to excel from my web page im getting this error.

can anyone please help me.

Thanks,
smartdev

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem with IE8 and Exporting to Excel that worked in all other browsers.

The culprit for me was setting "NoCache" for the response headers: 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Once I removed this response header for the Excel Export page, it worked.

By the way, your App might be doing this automatically, so you may have to programatically remove this response header in your page. Make sure you do that before outputting any content.

Comment: I found this occurs when either the no-cache or no-store HTTP cache control headers are returned with a content_disposition attachment. (I don't program in ASP so I don't know what its API names are for these headers). If you are worried about no-cacheing, just set 'must-revalidate', you don't need no-cache and no-store for file downloads.